# Custom Segue with UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown

Tags: objective-c, animation, curl, segue

I'd like create a custom segue to swap ViewControllers with a curl up animation but I can't find a way, What would be the -(void)perform for this?

I've got this

```
-(void)perform{
    UIViewController *dst = [self destinationViewController];
    UIViewController *src = [self sourceViewController];    
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    //change to set the time
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:src.view    cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But I don't get to change the view, anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, I solved it, for the record the only thing I had to do was add a Navigation Controller and then I could use custom segues like:

```
- (void) perform {
    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
    [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                    animations:^{
                        [src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];
                    }
                    completion:NULL];
}
```