# Custom segue in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode4.3, segue

I have a Master-Detail application.When the user selects a row in the MasterTable, I want to open another Table (not the DetailViewController). It should paper besides the MasterViewController, similar to the Facebook app on iPad.

I have a Custom segue from the MasterViewController to this table (DocumentViewController of type UITableViewController). This DocumentViewController is 'Embedded' in a navigation controller.

In short, the items on my storyboard look like this:

> navigationController->MasterViewController->navigationController->DocumentViewController.

The segue is from MasterViewController to navigationController.

Do I have to perform the segue in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"? Or do I have to use "performSegueWithIdentifier" in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the segue should be from MasterViewController to DocumentViewController.  Make sure to give it a unique identifier, and then reference what you want to do in the **prepareForSegue** in your MasterViewController.

Example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showList"]) {

        // gets indexPath for the currently selected row in my UITableView
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        // pull back some useful data from Core Data according to what was selected in my UITableView.
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // listDataItem is a property of the controller (in this case a UITableViewController)
        [[segue destinationViewController] setListDataItem:object];
    }
}
```

Comment: this will help me send data to the DocumentViewController.But how can i "animate" the segue so MasterVC moves to the left and DocumentVC sits besides the MasterVC?

Comment: @NetToiOS, this might be a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348605/custom-segue-with-uiviewanimationoptiontransitioncurldown.  Also, if this helps, please accept the answer.

Comment: the sample uses UIViewController,can i use UITableViewController since thats what MasterViewController and DocumentViewController are? And...i have accepted the answer :)

Comment: i have implemented both,"prepareforsegue" and "perform" methods.But when i run the application,none of the breakpoints are hit when i select a row in MasterVC.Any idea why is this?

Comment: The segue must be "linked" in your storyboard from the cell to your controller.  As for using UITableViewController... yes absolutely because they are subclasses of UIViewController, and because of polymorphism.

Comment: :- Thanks!!I was linking the segue from MasterVC to DocumentVC and thats why the breakpoint wasn't being hit.Thanks for the help,again!